# Pygame.camera in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, pygame, simplecv

I tried to Pygame.camera embedded in wxPython.

after some searching, I found out It can do with SDL_WINDOWID.  but I conldn't make it

The image is my Goal(what i want to make)
http://kalten.tistory.com/entry/wxPython

Can you help me? I need just simple example

I don't care even if Camera Viewer with Simplecv(not pygame.camera)

Thank you!!!^^ Have a nice day

```
    self.parent = parent
    self.hwnd = self.GetHandle()
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
    os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(self.hwnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Pygame Tutorials Camera Module Introduction](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html):

> Capturing a Live Stream The rest of this tutorial will be based around
>   capturing a live stream of images. For this, we will be using the
>   class below. As described, it will simply blit a constant stream of
>   camera frames to the screen, effectively showing live video. It is
>   basically what you would expect, looping get_image(), blitting to the
>   display surface, and flipping it. For performance reasons, we will be
>   supplying the camera with the same surface to use each time.

```
class Capture(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.size = (640,480)
         # create a display surface. standard pygame stuff
         self.display = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size, 0)

         # this is the same as what we saw before
         self.clist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
         if not self.clist:
             raise ValueError("Sorry, no cameras detected.")
         self.cam = pygame.camera.Camera(self.clist[0], self.size)
         self.cam.start()

         # create a surface to capture to.  for performance purposes
         # bit depth is the same as that of the display surface.
         self.snapshot = pygame.surface.Surface(self.size, 0, self.display)

     def get_and_flip(self):
         # if you don't want to tie the framerate to the camera, you can check 
         # if the camera has an image ready.  note that while this works
         # on most cameras, some will never return true.
         if self.cam.query_image():
             self.snapshot = self.cam.get_image(self.snapshot)

         # blit it to the display surface.  simple!
         self.display.blit(self.snapshot, (0,0))
         pygame.display.flip()

     def main(self):
         going = True
         while going:
             events = pygame.event.get()
             for e in events:
                 if e.type == QUIT or (e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE):
                     # close the camera safely
                     self.cam.stop()
                     going = False

             self.get_and_flip()
```

> Since get_image() is a blocking call that could take quite a bit of
>   time on a slow camera, this example uses query_image() to see if the
>   camera is ready. This allows you to separate the framerate of your
>   game from that of your camera. It is also possible to have the camera
>   capturing images in a separate thread, for approximately the same
>   performance gain, if you find that your camera does not support the
>   query_image() function correctly.